# User id dynamic pages .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this url 
**www.mydomain.com/profile.php?id=524170354d5a6** 
and I want to convert it to a friendly url like this :
**www.mydomain.com/profile/524170354d5a6**
I already tried with .htacces file but it doesn't work, my .htaccess is located inside my folder proyect (www/project->.htacces) Does this well located? or it has to be in (www/.htaccess)
my .htaccess contain the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)*$ /profile.php?id=$1
```

I saw several examples in Internet but none works, it could also be because my id contains numbers and letters? or my regex is wrong?

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: Apache 2.0 and a2enmod rewrite is enabled

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_, Where do you get redirected?

Comment: `.htacces` file must be in the directory `profile` along with `profile.php` because you are requesting `www/profile/ID` not `www/ID`

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` code needs to be in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`. Also modify your code slightly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make fancy url's, you'll need a rule to turn the 'ugly' url into the 'fancy' url. This is done via a so-called *external redirect*. You'll need an other rule to turn the 'fancy' url into the 'ugly' url internally, so that the server knows what to do. This will create a perpetual loop if you do not prevent that via the `END` flag (available from Apache 2.3.9 and up) or the `THE_REQUEST` trick.

```
#Rewrite fancy url to ugly url internally and stop rewriting completely
#RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [END]

#Internal rewrite pre-2.3.9
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /profile/(.*)\ .*$
RewriteRule ^ profile.php?id=%1 [L]

#Redirect the ugly url to the fancy url, so that the user will always see the fancy url in the address bar
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ profile/%1 [R,L]
```

(I can't test this on this computer)