# How to prevent infinite redirect loop on htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this situation:
all urls like `/sport.html` hide the real url `/archive.php?action=search&section=sport`

```
#This is the RULE:
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /archive.php?action=search&section=$1 [L]
```

Now I want to hide the real url and all direct access to the page `archive.php` but I receive the redirect loop error with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^archive\.php.*$ /404.html [F,NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you I resolved used both suggestions:
#THIS NOT MATCH 404 PAGE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^404\.html$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /archive.php?action=search&section=$1 [L]

#THIS REDIRECT DIRECT ACCESS TO 404
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /archive\.php.*
RewriteRule ^ /404.html? [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for isn't this:

```
RewriteRule ^archive\.php.*$ /404.html [F,NC,L]
```

As obviously, this causes a loop, since your first rule is rewriting to `archive.php`, and this rule rewrites it to something else, etc. etc.

Try this instead of the above rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /archive\.php
RewriteRule ^ /404.html [F,L]
```

Or, if you want to be fancy about it:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /archive\.php\?action=search&section=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make sure your first rule doesn't match `404.html`. You can use `RewriteCond` for that. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for more information about that.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^404\.html$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /archive.php?action=search&section=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please note that this fixes the internal server error, but it doesn't 'hide' the real url. You'll need a redirect for that. You can find out how to do that properly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030491/redirect-one-url-to-another-url-using-htaccess/18030624#18030624) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067377/user-id-dynamic-pages-htaccess/19067462#19067462).

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is impossible to hide real file because of Apache' system.

But in your archive.php, you can test the current URL and redirect it to sport.html if this is not "sports.html".

Comment: No, it is possible. See the documentation I link in my answer.