# Making a clean URL with php arguments in it

Tags: php, .htaccess

So far, I have made my .htaccess to let me remove the ".php" extension, but that isn't enough for me. I want to be so that example.com/test?id=asdfjK could be able to be accessed as example.com/asdfjK. So that it accepts only the main php get argument in the URL (I don't know what to call them.

Here is my .htaccess file so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /image.php?ID=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /image.php?ID=$1
```

Comment: Does anyone that is on right now know about how to do this? I've read other questions, but the answers haven't helped me.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to differentiate between what gets sent to `index.php` and what gets sent to `image.php`. The patterns are identical, which means everything will match the first one and nothing will get routed to `image.php`. You've got to add something to the url so that you can match against it. Something like:

```
http://example.com/image/abcdefg123456
```

And that means the htaccess file would look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^image/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ image.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now when I go to my domain and use /image/sadfklj9 (random code), Chrome loads for a second or two then tells me it runs a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP arguments after the question mark are called the "query string".

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This should redirect anything from:

```
http://example.com/abc123
```

To:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=abc123
```

See also:

- [htaccess rewrite for query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)
- [.htaccess rewrite query string as path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003319/htaccess-rewrite-query-string-as-path)
- [How to prevent infinite redirect loop on htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454261/how-to-prevent-infinite-redirect-loop-on-htaccess)

Comment: That didn't work :(. The examples just gives me the same error as in my previous comment on the answer above.

Comment: I think you can get around the infinite redirect by putting in a RewriteCond above your rule.  Basically, I think because the rule matches the rewritten output, it will rewrite it again (and again, and so forth).  A condition prevents that by only applying the rule if it hasn't already been rewritten.  See the updated answer above.